# Multiple APIs within RAILS application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading

I have a simple rails application that send API requests to 10 different providers.

The procedure:

- user clicks on a button
- multiple requests sent to different APIs (there are 10 providers - means 10 requests total)
- Each provider returns response in ~3 seconds
- User wait 10*3sec = 30 seconds for a single user request.

Using Heroku (free version), Can you please let me know what the best option to reduce response time with Rails 4 (using threads, workers, etc...)? examples are much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolve this by using the simple rails thread.

```
threads << Thread.new{something to be done...}
threads << Thread.new{something to be done...}
threads << Thread.new{something to be done...}

threads.map &:join // Wait for all threads to be completed and then continue
```